# Will a LocalDB create a database on execution if one does not exist?

Tags: database, localdb

I am using LocalDB for storing individual data.  The program I am making will be a simple .exe, so no installer needed.

I want to know if the program will automatically create a DB when it realizes there is not one?  If not, how do I have the program do this?

I used the DataSet services in my IDE to create mine.

Comment: Obviously it depends. LocalDB doesn't need SQL server (of course it resides on their PC). SQL server CE works the same way. I'm not really sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: If your app uses a database, your *installer* should install a database as well. Of course, you won't include SQL Server with your installer, so it should be a prerequisite or it should include something like LocalDB. If it uses a DB, your app doesn't seem to be **that** simple. :P
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: The behaviour you WANT isnt clear? do you WANT a seperate instace on each machine or do you want some Database running from a server somewhere that all instances of yur application access?

Comment: Right, I need just a local DB for storing individual data, no need to connect to any external sources. The program I am making will be a simple .exe, so no installer needed. I want to know if when the program is run will it automatically create a DB when it realizes there is not one, as I obviously have one set up in my development environment...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you need a database? You could just write/read from a xml or json file

Comment: I think you are looking for CE.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx

Comment: Thats a different question. Can you reword it to ask that?